# Dynamic Variables to access class methods in Ruby

Tags: ruby, dynamic-variables

Working in Ruby, we have to use a 3rd party Framework, which has a class setup something like this:

```
class Foo 

    attr_accessor :bar

    def initialize() 
    end

end

class Poorly_Designed_Class

    attr_accessor :thing1
    attr_accessor :thing2
    attr_accessor :thing3
    attr_accessor :thing4
    attr_accessor :thing5

    # through :thing_n .. number defined at runtime

    def initialize()
        @thing1 = Foo.new
        @thing2 = Foo.new
        @thing3 = Foo.new
        @thing4 = Foo.new
        @thing5 = Foo.new
    end

end
```

I don't know how many "things" there are until run time. there could be 5 or their could be 50.

What I would like to do is something like:

```
pdc = Poorly_Designed_Class.new
for i in 0..numberOfThings do
    pdc."thing#{i}".bar = value[i]
end
```

The above doesn't work.

I've also tried accessing it via:

```
instance_variable_set("pdc.thing#{i}.bar",value)
```

I understand that the class should be using an array or hash. Unfortunately I can't do anything about how the class is designed and we have to use it.

Is what i'm trying to do even possible?

Comment: First try to find out name of the hash instance variable: `pdc.instance_variables`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could either try to call the getter (preferably, since it honors encapsulation):

```
pdc = PoorlyDesignedClass.new
1.upto(number_of_things.times do |i|
  pdc.public_send(:"thing#{i}").bar = value[i]
end
```

or get the instance variable (less preferred, since it breaks encapsulation):

```
pdc = PoorlyDesignedClass.new
1.upto(number_of_things) do |i|
  pdc.instance_variable_get(:"@thing#{i}").bar = value[i]
end
```

So, you were on the right track, there were just two problems with your code: instance variable names start with an `@` sign, and `.` is not a legal character in an identifier.

Answer (score 0):

You're using [`Object#instance_variable_set`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Object.html#method-i-instance_variable_set) incorrectly. The first argument must be a string or a symbol representing the name of an instance variable including the `@` prefix: e.g. `"@thing{i}"`. However you actually want to *get* the value of an instance variable and then send `#bar=` to it. That can be done with [`Object#instance_variable_get`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Object.html#method-i-instance_variable_get):

```
1.upto(numberOfThings) { |i| pdc.instance_variable_get("@thing#{i}").bar = value[i] }
```

That's a bit long and since `attr_acessor :thingX` defines getter methods, it's usually preferable to call them with [`Object#public_send`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Object.html#method-i-public_send) instead of directly accessing the instance variable (a getter method might do something else than just returning a value):

```
1.upto(numberOfThings) { |i| pdc.public_send("thing#{i}").bar = value[i] }
```